# Build top-list from player-player duel result

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a list of duels between players. The data consists of 2 user IDs, where the first one is the winner.

How can I build a graph of this list to find the best players?

Furthermore, how do I decide what it means to be best?
Perhaps players should be ranked by the number of opponents beaten, and the rank of those opponents (recursively).
I have previously tried doing this using the PageRank algorithm, but it does not account for losses in a good way (i.e. the rank should go down from a loss).

For example:

```
1 won against 3
1 won against 4
1 won against 5
2 won against 1
```

This list should put 2 at the top, because it beat 1.

This presents one problem - it should be required to duel those with a high rank.
Those who have not dueled players above a certain rank should be told to do so, in order to be in the top-list.

Comment: Can you clarify **top** players?? You require building a graph but ask for a list of top players, so a more precise definition of top players would help to come up with a specific answer to your issue.

Comment: @OscarBroman can you have multiple games between the same players? Can you have cycles in the duel history?

Comment: @ilim First off I'd like to clarify that I have not had time to review your answer and give it a try. Hopefully I will do so this weekend. I appreciate it!

I'll update my question momentarily with more background about what it means to be in the top.

Comment: @OscarBroman No worries. What you propose may work more efficiently than my answer if your graph is very large and you limit the depth of recursion you reach instead of traversing the entire graph. My answer did traverse the entire graph and was based mainly on theoretical concepts rather than practical constraints, even though I did mention the time complexity of the solution I thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define player X beating player Y as a relation such that there exists vertices X and Y and there exists **an edge from Y to X**.

Then, after processing all game information, you may run [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the graph, recording in some array A the nodes from which you can not traverse *deeper*.
As you did not specify that the given graph is a tree, considering also that the edges are directed, **there are no guarantees that DFS starting from any node will converge to a single root**, so you need to keep some sort of a list of such nodes that *beat* others.

Once that initial traversal is done, reverse all the edges, and run a DFS for each tree in the forest that is your graph and root of each is an element in A. As you traverse the tree rooted in A[i], record in each node the depth it is located at, relative to the root node, A[i].

Then on, depending on your definition of *top* players, you may traverse the roots in A and go as deep as that definition allows you to, picking every element you encounter. If the final list you require should actually sort the nodes descendant of different roots in A, you may sort the final structure you will have your list in, using the depth as the comparison criterion. Aside from the final sorting I mentioned, as all we did so far is DFS, this approach is **O(V+E)**, V being the number of vertices and E, the number of edges. If you take into account the sorting of elements in different trees, then you'd have an overall complexity of **O((V+E) + VlogV)**.

If you are willing to sacrifice a bit more of the performance, then you may connect the roots in A to a global root R (i.e. add node R to graph and edges from R to each A[i]) and run Dijkstra's algorithm, visiting the nodes with less depth first, and basically appending each visited node to your list until you consider you list is large enough, based on your definition of **top** players.

Note that this solution does not work if you have cycles in the graph, regardless of whether you use DFS or Dijkstra's for the final traversal. However it may be adapted to players having multiple matches by using edges with positive weights. An edge from X to Y with weight k would then indicate the number of times X defeated Y, which you will take into account while updating the depth of node during your traversal with DFS.